# The idiomatic approach to mounting "configuration" volumes on ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I have a docker container that I would like to "port" to ECS. My `Dockerfile` contains a `VOLUME` instruction:

> `VOLUME /app/configuration`

So using docker on a linux machine, you just point to the folder you would like to associate the VOLUME to either using `docker run` or in the `docker-compose` file. This is already configured by myself with values.

What I don't know, is how to accomplish the same thing on ECS? Is there an idiom for using volumes containing configurations?

I have followed the [ECS Volumes Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html), but this just tells you how to use a blank volume for the intent of persistence, not how to use a volume with configuration data.

The options I think I have:

- Store configuration information in S3, not sure if this is a good idea because there are database secrets involved. I suppose that this can be locked down using IAM Policies?
- Maybe use an EFS volume? The idea is then mount the EFS volume somewhere, put the configuration data on it, then mount that volume on ECS?

So while I know how to do this in Docker, what's the best way to approach this on AWS?

Comment: Use the [AWS Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) to store passwords / URLs / etc.